# What is a single word for “already made path”

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word for “already made path”?

For example "to walk in a person's [already made path]"

Comment: Actually, you could just leave everything out. To walk in a person’s path can only be attempted if they have actually left one to walk in.

Comment: @tchrist I want to emphasise the fact that the path has "already been made" by the person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific example, it would most often be said as

**To walk in a person's footsteps**

This is a common expression that can be used literally and figuratively to to mean "to follow the path already made by someone".

A footstep, or course, is the impression made by someone when they create or follow a path.

Noting your concern about "to walk in a person's path" (without the emphasis on it already having been made), you can walk in a persons path by stepping in front of them as they are making a path. (It has not already been made.) Better in this case, I think, would be "to walk *into* a persons path". But, yes, there is an ambiguity in this case.

By the way, if this answer fits what you are thinking, you should edit your question to something like "**What is a single word for “already made path**”

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "well-worn" (if hyphenation is considered one word)?

Answer (score -1):

I think the order would be footsteps walkway path trail another meaning could be direction  as in follow their direction